# What are the isomorphisms in the category of vector spaces, $Vec_K$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, category-theory

Here is an interesting question from "The Rising Sea" book of Algebraic Geometry: [http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGapr2915public.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGapr2915public.pdf)

1.2.3 Example. Consider the category $Vec_K$ of vector spaces over a field $K$. The objects are $K$-vector spaces, and the morphisms are linear transformations. What are the isomorphisms?

I would say that the isomorphisms are the invertible linear transformations, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There's not much more to say about this, except to remark that it suffices to require that the linear transformation is invertible as a map of sets; this kind of thing isn't always true in other concrete categories.

Answer (score -2):

Question: "I would say that the isomorphisms are the invertible linear transformations, is that correct?"

Answer: If $C$ is any category and $U,V$ objects in $C$, we define $U$ to be isomorphic to $V$ (written $U \cong V$) iff there are morphisms (in $C$) $f:U \rightarrow V$ and $g: V\rightarrow U$ such that $f\circ g=Id_V$ and $g \circ f=Id_U$. In your case the maps $f,g$ are invertible linear maps/linear transformations between vector spaces.

Comment: It's just the definition of isomorphism in a general category.